# C++ String user input into Class Object?

Tags: c++, class, object, getline

Let's say i have some class Employee ,and an object Director.
For example :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 class Employee
{
 public:
 string firsName;
 string lastName;
 int age;
};

 int main()
{
 Employee Director;
 Director.firstName = "Smith";
 etc....
}

etc...

return 0:
}
```

How i use a String input to let the user enter Director.firstName and etc. into the object?

```
cout<<"Enter Directors name: " << endl;
Director.firstName = getline(cin ,firstName);
```

Thank u very much in advance !

Comment: hint: what does `getline(cin, firstname)` return?

Comment: You need to pass the string you want to read into to `getline`. That string is `Director.firstname`.

Comment: it doesn't compile it ,says 'firstName' wasn't declared in that scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getline` is used differently. You should pass the string as a reference in which the result should be written. The return value of the function is a reference to the stream, which you can ignore.

In order to pass the `firstName` you need to add the object of which you want to access the member, like you originally did with the left hand of the assignment.

```
getline(cin, Director.firstName);
```

So don't use the assignment operator (`=`) here.

Answer (score 1):

change `Director.firstName = getline(cin, firstName);`
to `getline(cin, Director.firstName);`